# This variable doesn't exist in the current context

Tags: c#, .net

```
string[,] cusName = { { "John", "Smith" }, { "Will", "James"} , { "Bryan", "Doe" } };

for (int x = 0; x < cusName.GetLength(x); x++)
{
    for (int j = x + 1; j < cusName.GetLength(j); j++)
    {
        Console.Write("{0} ", cusName[x, j]);
    }
    Console.Write("{0} ", cusName[x, j]);
}
```

My problem is that the last `Console.Write` always produces an error. It says that the variable `j` doesn't exist in the current context.

Comment: because it doesn't, the last `Console.Write` is after the `for` that `j` is scoped to

Comment: Well it *doesn't*. It only exist *inside* the inner loop.

Comment: the second console.write call is outside of the inner for loop. the `j` variable is in scope only inside the inner for loop. just remove the second console.write call and you're good.  there is a second problem with this code, the `GetLength` argument is supposed to be the subscript index ("dimension"), not the loop variable.

Comment: _it says that the variable "j" doesn't exist_ - but if it did exist then the exception would have told you that it was out of range. Just remove that WriteLine,

Comment: if I do that then the incremented j will not be used? like I want the last names of the array to be showed too. so how can I like Globalize the j?

Comment: And `cusName.GetLength(j)` and `cusName.GetLength(x)` will also throw exceptions.

Comment: to achieve that, you use the break condition of the for loop. arrays in C# are zero based, so they go from 0 to length-1, therefore your use of the `<` comparison operator is fine and should include the last item inside the loop. but as already mentioned, take care you fix your `GetLength` arguments, as it is currently written it will lead to bogus results and more exceptions. you'll probably want 0 for last names and 1 for first names, respectively.

Comment: Ok. I totally get it now. I tried to remove the last console.write and it shows more errors. Yeah I should just use for (int j = 0; j < cusNames.GetLenth(1); j++) haha thank you so much. Im very dumb. I should just clarify all before posting a question here. sorry guys

Comment: I vote to close after OP's ^ comment and seconds after, three answers of 40k <= rep <= 190k contributors appear. seriously?

Comment: @dlatikay It took me a little bit longer than just seconds. When I started writing the answer, there was no mention of the `GetLength` calls in the comments. And I consider that use problematic enough that it deserves a proper explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I want to have like semi global variable for loops. then I should just use a while? Am I correct?

Not quite. The type of loop used and the scope of variables are not as closely related as you think.

The first "argument" of a for loop is meant to be used for a variable declaration and initialization, but actually you can (ab)use it to execute any valid statement. (don't! its not the way to write clean and maintainable code). You can even leave it blank and use a variable you declared earlier, elsewhere:

```
var j = 42;
for(; j > 0; --j)
{
    /* do something */
}
/* now, j is still in scope */
Console.WriteLine(j);
```

This is strongly discouraged because it is less readable than the normal syntax, and you would need to know one more obscure bit of information: the value of the loop variable after the last loop execution (it is the final value determined by the break condition plus one increment/decrement) - this is easy to get wrong and introduce one-off-errors.

Few C# beginners know that C# loop syntax (which has many similarities with C) is not constrained to the `for(declaration; condition; increment)` pattern at all. The following is valid and working code, if you wanted to start an obfuscated C# code competition:

```
for (int i = 11, j = new Random().Next(33) + 1; i * j < 65536; Console.WriteLine(++j))
{
    ++i;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As others already pointed out in the comments, you cannot access `j` outside of the loop it was being declared for. So you would either have to declare `j` *before* the loop, or access the last index in a different way than reusing `j`.

That being said, it’s unclear what you want to do with your code, and it’s likely that you don’t actually want to have that `Console.Write` there at all.

There is a big problem with your code btw:

```
for (int x = 0; x < cusName.GetLength(x); x++)
```

This for-loop will increment `x` as long as it is smaller than `cusName.GetLength(x)`. [`Array.GetLength`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.getlength.aspx) is used to get the element count of a dimension in a multi-dimensional array. Since your array has two dimensions, the **only** valid calls you could make to `GetLength`  are `GetLength(0)` for the first dimension, and `GetLength(1)` for the second dimension. Having a variable in there, especially one that increments within a loop, is very likely to break.

I assume that you originally wanted to do something like this:

```
for (int x = 0; x < cusName.GetLength(0); x++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < cusName.GetLength(1); j++)
    {
        Console.Write("{0} ", cusName[x, j]);
    }
}
```

---

If you wanted to continue using a loop variable after the loop, you could declare it before:

```
int j;
for (j = 0; j < cusName.GetLength(1); j++)
{
    …
}
Console.Write(j);
```

Note that after the loop, `j` has the value `cusName.GetLength(1)` since that is the way loops work: After every loop iteration, the variable will be incremented, and the loop body will be executed if the condition (`j < cusName.GetLength(1)`) is true. So the for loop will always end with another incrementation of the loop variable.

This means that if you use the loop variable as an index, then that index will be out of bounds for the array after the loop. So you should keep that in mind if you want to reuse the variable.

Often, it’s easier and clearer if you don’t use the loop variable but instead calculate the last index separately again:

```
cusName[x, cusName.GetLength(1) - 1])
```

Comment: Yess! Thank and I totally understands the logic of that code of yours. thank you so much.

Comment: If I want to have like semi global variable for loops. then I should just use a while? Am I Correct?

Comment: You can just declare the variable before the loop, i.e. `int x; for(x = 0; …` That way, the variable is declared in the block directly outside of the for loop, so you can continue using it afterwards. Note though that the loop variable will have the value of `cusName.GetLength(0)` then, so accessing the array with that will be invalid (since the number is now one larger than the last index – that’s why the loop stopped iterating)

Answer (score 1):

When you define a variable inside a `for` loop, as in `for(int j=...)`, that variable exists only inside the loop. If you want to access that variable outside the loop, declare it outside:

```
int j;
for(j = ...)
```

Answer (score 1):

you should modify your code as below:

```
    string[,] cusName = { {"John", "Smith"}, {"Will","James"}, { "Bryan", "Doe" } };

    int j=0;

    for(int x = 0; x < cusName.GetLength(x); x++)
    {
        for (j = x + 1; j < cusName.GetLength(j); j++)
        {

            Console.Write("{0} ", cusName[x,j]);

        }
        Console.Write("{0} ", cusName[x, j]);
    }
```